# Why does Hurricane Ian show a long tail off to the North-East on doppler radar?

Tags: meteorology

I was looking at the radar on the Weather Channel website and I noticed something that I don't think I've ever seen before.

Screen shot from 11:30 AM EST 9/29
[image]

Hurricane/Tropical Storm Ian can be seen in the lower left of the screenshot.  However, there appears to be a massive tail that extends from the storm, with the tail reaching as far north as Boston.

Is this typical of hurricanes?  Is this a glitch in the radar?  Is this unrelated to Ian?  Or is this something rare?

Comment: There is a upper level mid latitue trough - https://tropic.ssec.wisc.edu/real-time/atlantic/winds/wg8vor1.GIF oirented NE to SW that is stretching the divergence of that hurricane and causing rain.https://forecast.weather.gov/glossary.php?word=positive-tilt+trough#:~:text=Positive%2Dtilt%20Trough,all%20other%20factors%20are%20equal.

Comment: https://tropic.ssec.wisc.edu/real-time/atlantic/winds/wg8vor2.GIF Present in multiple levels of the atmosphere. Quite strong

Comment: https://www.npr.org/2022/09/27/1125366281/hurricane-ian-track-difficult-predict Storm is recurving due to the mid latitude trough.

Comment: @gansub Maybe you could turn those comments into an answer?

Comment: @Jean-MariePrival Over the next 2 days sure.